# How to play animations for children of AnimationNodeStateMachine in godot4.2?

Tags: godot, godot4

[image]

How do I use AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback.travel to call the three animations of attack_1, attack_2, and attack_3 in the child attack_state when using AnimationTree?

I tried playing it, but it didn't work:

```
@onready var attack_state_machine: AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback = $AnimationTree.get("parameters/attack_state")

# @onready var attack_state_machine: AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback = $AnimationTree.get("parameters/playback/attack_state")

attack_state_machine.travel("attack_1")
```

and

```
@onready var animation_state_machine: AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback = $AnimationTree.get("parameters/playback")

animation_state_machine.travel("attack_state/attack_1")
```

Comment: It should be like this：


var attack_state_machine: AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback = $AnimationTree.get("parameters/attack_state/playback")                                                             
                                                       
attack_state_machine.travel("attack_1")

Comment: But don't play the animation